# What is the short cut of switching control using Magnet in MacOS

Tags: macos

I am splitting the window using [Magnet](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766) (MacOS software) in MacBook Air; let's say I am breaking two Chrome (viewing YouTube and Google Docs simultaneously).

I wish to use shortcuts to handle/jump between two tabs, for example: Typing in Google Docs and switching to youtube to start playing the video, then back to Google Docs typing without using my mouse.

[image: tabs]

Comment: Haven’t used Magnet, but use another tool for splitting/snapping, can’t remember the name. But my tool’s shortcut keys are all window moving/snapping. Yours could be different, you’d need to read the Magnet docs, but quite likely they also just position the windows. To switch between windows, you can see if Chrome has that option (Ctrl-tab should work if those are your only tabs, or maybe even just your 2 most recent tabs), and the macOS Cmd-Tab will switch between apps (so you could do this with 1 Safari window and 1 Chrome).

Comment: Does this help? https://defkey.com/magnet-macos-shortcuts

Comment: @jimtut ctrl-tab works between different apps, however, I wish to switch in same app(two windows of chrome).

Comment: @Peregrino69 I think it didn't mention how to switch.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I have edited the question and added the photo; thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As worded ("What is the short cut of switching control using Magnet in MacOS"), **you can't do it**.  Magnet simply doesn't support it: https://defkey.com/magnet-macos-shortcuts

I left a comment saying that you could use Chrome's built-in tab switcher for this, but that's wrong.  Ctrl-Tab will go to the "next tab", but only in the same window.

Chrome has a TON of extensions for tab management, some of which will let you do this (but be careful of ones that want to "read data on all your websites", that just doesn't seem safe to me).

But, the best out-of-the-box (no extensions needed) way that I can think of doing this is to use Chrome **and** Safari, and use macOS's built-in Cmd-Tab to switch between the 2 windows.